# Why does my simple test NPObject not work?

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin, npruntime

I have this getValue method + NPclass methods:

```
static bool hasmethod(NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier name)
{
    return true;
}
static NPObject* allocate (NPP npp, NPClass *aClass)
{
    return  browser-> createobject(npp, aClass);
}
static bool hasProperty(NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier name)
{
     return true;
}
static bool getProperty (NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier name, NPVariant *result)
{
   if (!result) 
       return false;
   INT32_TO_NPVARIANT(50, *result);
   return true;
}
static void deallocate (NPObject *npobj)
{
   browser -> memfree(npobj);
}
static bool enumerate(NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier **value, uint32_t *count)
{
    return false;
}
static bool defaultInvoke(NPObject* obj, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount,     NPVariant *result)
{
    if (!result) 
    return false;
    INT32_TO_NPVARIANT(42, *result);
    return true;
}
static bool setProperty (NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier name, const NPVariant *value)
{
    return false;
}  
static void invalidate(NPObject *npobj)
{
}
static bool removeProperty (NPObject *npobj,NPIdentifier name)
{
    return false;
}
NPError NPP_GetValue(NPP instance, NPPVariable variable, void *value)
{
    if (! instance)
    {
        return NPERR_INVALID_INSTANCE_ERROR;
    }
struct NPClass class;
class.structVersion = NP_CLASS_STRUCT_VERSION;
class.construct = NULL;
class.deallocate = deallocate;
class.hasMethod = hasmethod;
class.getProperty= getProperty;
class.enumerate= enumerate;
class.removeProperty= removeProperty;
class.hasProperty = hasProperty;
class.invoke = pinvoke;
class.invokeDefault = defaultInvoke;
class.invalidate = invalidate;
class.setProperty = setProperty;
class.allocate = allocate;
if (variable == NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject)
{
    void **v = (void **)value;
    struct NPObject *object = NPN_CreateObject(instance, &class);
    NPN_RetainObject(object);
    *v = object;
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}
return NPERR_GENERIC_ERROR;
}
```

Here are the two other methods the class points to:

```
 bool hasmethod(NPObject *npobj, NPIdentifier name)
 {
     return true;
 }

static bool pinvoke(NPObject* obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result)
{
    if (!result) 
    return false;
    INT32_TO_NPVARIANT(32, *result);
    return true;
}
```

Basically, I wanted the object to return 32 when anything was called just to test.

Here are my create & retain methods:

```
NPObject *NPN_CreateObject(NPP npp, NPClass *aClass)
{
    return browser->createobject(npp, aClass);
}

NPObject *NPN_RetainObject(NPObject *npobj)
{
    return browser->retainobject(npobj);
}
```

In my Javascript:

```
        <embed type="application/x-my-extension" id="pluginId">
            <script>
            var plugin = document.getElementById("pluginId");
            console.log(plugin.something);
```

The window is drawn on the page, but the console outputs undefined.
Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: Georg suggested that the browser was crashing due to infinite recursion with my allocate method.  Here is the new one:

```
 void* NPN_MemAlloc(uint32_t size)
 {
     return browser->memalloc(size);
 }
 static NPObject* allocate (NPP npp, NPClass *aClass)
 {
   NPObject* object = (NPObject*)NPN_MemAlloc(sizeof(NPObject));
   if (!object)
   {
    return NULL;
   }
   memset(object, 0, sizeof(NPObject));
   return object;
 }
```

The plugin still crashes.

Update 2: I made the object Instance specific

```
typedef struct PluginInstance {
  NPP npp;
  NPWindow window;
  NPObject *object;
}PluginInstance;
```

In my NPP_New method I have

```
 PluginInstance *newInstance = (PluginInstance*)malloc(sizeof(PluginInstance));
 bzero(newInstance, sizeof(PluginInstance));
 newInstance -> object = NPN_CreateObject(instance, &class);
 newInstance->npp = instance;
 instance->pdata = newInstance;
```

In my getValue method:

```
    NPObject* obj = ((PluginInstance *) (instance->pdata)) -> object;
    void **v = (void **)value;
    NPN_RetainObject(obj);
    *v = obj;
```

still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't only fill out parts of the `NPClass` functions, most notably you are missing `hasProperty` & `getProperty`. Browsers may handle other missing functions, but as far as i know they are not required to.

Also note that your `NPP_GetValue()` should only return the scriptable object for `variable == NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject`.
You should then create scriptable objects per plugin instance (keep in mind that multiple instances of your plugin can run concurrently) and not forget to `NPN_Release()` the scriptable object when your plugin goes away.
`pinvoke()` could be improved to:

```
static bool pinvoke(NPObject* obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant *args, 
                    uint32_t argCount, NPVariant *result)
{
    if (!result) 
        return false;
    INT32_TO_NPVARIANT(32, *result);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I added stub methods for all of the NPclass pointers except for construct and I set value to NPObject only the the NPPVpluginScriptableObject case. Instead of not doing anything, the plugin now crashes. Thanks for your help. I suppose crashing is better than not doing anything because that means its doing something. Any other suggestions? I updated the code above with my changes.  I will create objects per instance later..right now I just want to see the test work.

Comment: @John: calling `browser->createObject()` from `allocate()` results in the browser calling your `allocate()` function again, so you currently probably get infinite recursion. You need to create the `NPOject` in allocate, see e.g. [Mozillas test plugin](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/plugins/test/testplugin/nptest.cpp#1888). By the way, please add updates to your questions instead of changing them whole, otherwise existing answers suddenly dont fit the question anymore.

Comment: @Georg_Fritzsche That was a great idea.  Sorry about not using an update, I'll  be sure to do that from now on.  I showed my new allocate function up above based on the mozilla sample code (thank you for that!).  However, still no change.  I am going to make getValue instance specific to see if that changes anything, but I am not optimistic.  Do you see anything else wrong?  If this information helps, the plugin only crashes if I call plugin.something in my javascript, otherwise it creates the window just fine.

Comment: @John: Nothing jumps out on me - try [debugging it](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Debugging+Plugins) to see where it crashes? Also you now create a new `NPObject` everytime `NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject` is requested - just return the same `NPObject` for the same `NPP` instances.

Comment: I made it instance specific.  Trying to debug now.

Comment: I needed to add the (NPFunctionPointers) to the class....But it also didn't work for all of your reasons too, so thanks!!